# Bash getops option variables are empty

Tags: bash, getopts

Just got started with using getops, so this one is most likely a rookie error.

I want to pass 2 options for the user to define; -e (env) and -p (project)

```
./my-script.sh -e development -p hello-world
```

Here is my code so far:

```
while getopts "e:p:" option; do
    case $option in
        e) # declare env
            ENV=$OPTARG
        ;;
        p) # declare project 
            PROJECT=$OPTARG
        ;;
    esac
done

echo "env is $ENV"
echo "project is $PROJECT"
```

However, when I echo the 2 options, both are empty.

I believe the "e:p:" config is correct, as succeeding with : means a value is required. I've seen some resources online about OPTIND, but couldn't get that to work.

What am I missing to be able to pass the ENV and PROJECT options for usage in the rest of my script? Thank you.

Comment: This looks correct to me, and works when I test it. Is that the entire script? Does it have a shebang line (i.e. something like `#!/bin/bash` at the very beginning)? Are you sure it's running in bash (although it should work in any POSIX-ish shell)?

Comment: You should `shift $(($OPTIND - 1))` after the `done` and add a shebang 1st line as Gordon suggests. Have a look at the advanced bash scripting guide https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#GETOPTSOPT

I prefer bash argument parsing with `/usr/bin/getopt`. `man getopt` should show you an example script.

Answer (score -2):

You need to provide the arguments to `getopts`, by supplying them in the optstring :
replace `getopts "e:p:" option` with `getopts "e:p: $*" option`.

Comment: That's incorrect. I think you're mixing up `getopts` with `getopt` (although that's not the right way to run `getopt` either).